# Perform edit and delete operation for arrays in array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to or add some arrays in questionnaire
I could reach what's inside section but don't know how to reach inside the question array so I can delete it or add something in it.

```
{
  "questionnaire": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "questionnaireName": "Inscription",
      "section": [
        {
          "sectionName": "section",
          "question": [
            {
              "questionName": "votre moyenne?",
              "type": "checkbox",
              "answer": [
                {
                  "id": "",
                  "answerName": "14"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

the editquestionnaire.ts looks like this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.identifiant = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.afficherQuestionnaire();

  }
  afficherQuestionnaire(){
    this.questionnaire.getQuestionnaireParId(this.identifiant).subscribe(Response=>{
      this.ques=Response
    })
  }
  editquestionnaire(t){
    console.log(t);
    this.questionnaire.modifierQuestionnaire(t).subscribe(Response=>{
      this.afficherQuestionnaire();
  })
}
removeSection(i){
  this.ques['section'].splice(i,1);   
}
```

the editquestionnaire.html looks like this

```
<div *ngIf="ques">
   questionnaire

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ques.questionnaireName" >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let r of ques.section;let i=index;" >
    <h3>section</h3>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="r.sectionName" >
        <button type="button" (click)="removeSection(i)">delete section</button>

        <ng-container  *ngFor="let d of r.question">
            <h5>question</h5>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="d.questionName" >
            <ng-container *ngFor="let j of d.answer">
                <h6>answer</h6>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="j.answerName">
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <button type="button" (click)="editquestionnaire(ques)">submit</button>

</div>
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you want to pre-fill the data in form?

Comment: @MaruthiEranki yup that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: Check if my suggestion works for you

Answer (score 0):

In Edit form/fields you need to use `[(ngModel)]="ques.questionnaireName"` instead of `value="{{ques.questionnaireName}}"`

**[(ngModel)]** is used for two way binding for variables. if you dont have knowledge about you can [click here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: Yes I know the two way binding for variables but the thing is it will show me the data I get from JSON file but I can't add any other formControl or formGroup in that way you can only rewrite the values but you can't add other values

Comment: you can add other values also using **[(ngModel)]="ques.otherValue"** to any HTML control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pre-filling the data in your form, you have to use `[value]='val'`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let questionnaire of questionnaireArray">
  <ng-containter *ngFor="let section of questionnaire.section>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let question of section.question">
      <input [(ngModel)]='question.questionName' [value]='question.questionName'
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

You should have three for loops to reach questionName which is complexity of n^3. I feel you can redesign your json in better way. All that you have to change in `<input>` is add `[value]` and `[(ngModel)]`. Hope this helped you.

Comment: the thing is it will show me the data I get from JSON file but I can't add any other formControl or formGroup in that way you can only rewrite the values but you can't add other values plus I don't know how to put the whole thing in a form so I can submit eventually @MaruthiEranki

Comment: It is two way binding and you don't have any hassles for getting that data from the form. When you change that value here in form, then it'll update in JSON too. So, you can submit that JSON object

Comment: Can you tell your problem briefly?

Comment: I changed the whole question, I added some things. sorry for not being clear at first. I used your advice so thank you for that @MaruthiEranki

Comment: Are you looking to delete array? If my suggestion is helpful,  consider to upvote.

Comment: I could delete the section with the removeSection() but i couldn't access to question so I can delete it .Any suggestions @MaruthiEranki ?

Comment: Send the object in parameters to function on button click. In that case, object d should be passed to function. That object will have array and you can do operations in that object